# Why does Python 3.4.3 using lxml not output print statement correctly?

Tags: python, lxml, pretty-print

While I'm trying to run through an lxml tutorial, I couldn't help but wonder why when I use the print command, the output to the screen keeps wanting to put everything on one line even with pretty_print=True.

So say I just installed Python 3.4.3 64-bit and installed lxml-3.4.0.win32-py3.4.exe after Python was installed.

Then, in IDLE or at the python.exe cmd prompt, I do the following:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML('<root><a><b/></a></root>')
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

What I (and the tutorial) expected was the following output to the screen:

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b/>
  </a>
</root>
```

But what I actually see in both IDLE and the python cmd prompt in the Windows 7 is this:

```
b'<root>\n  <a>\n    <b/>\n  </a>\n</root>\n'
```

So why does the interpreter do this?  Is there a way to toggle between single-line mode and the more normal standard output?  And perhaps more importantly, if I want to write this XML to a file, will Python with the lxml insist on putting the \n and everything else on a line instead of pretty-printing this the way it's supposed to?

Thanks,
Johnny

Comment: try to print it in a console, you'll see it works. You're seeing the representation of the linefeeds, not the linefeeds themselves...

Comment: Tried this in both the Python 3.4.3 console and in IDLE.  It's only when I put the encoding='unicode' as an argument in tostring as the person who answered below suggested did it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is the representation of the bytes string. You can write bytes directly to a file:

```
with open("file.xml", "wb") as output:
    output.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

`print` expects an unicode string, so you have to encode to unicode:

```
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode'))
```

Comment: Yep, tried this and it works.  Funny they didn't mention this in the tutorial for lxml at http://lxml.de/tutorial.html.  Is it because some interpreters default to unicode?  Or is it an oversight by the tutorial authors?